# Firebase sending notification to the user if he subscribed to a topic of it (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can send notifications to individual users using their FCM token, and I can also send notifications to a group of users who have subscribed to a specific "topic". However, I want to combine these functionalities in a way that allows me to send a notification to a user only if they have subscribed to the relevant topic.

Is it possible to achieve this with Firebase, or should I consider using an alternative approach?

I tried to send a message like that:

```
  "message": {
    "topic" : "foo-bar",
    "notification": {
      "body": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
      "title": "FCM Message"
    },
    "token":  ""
  }
```

But in that case it throws me an error that i can use only "topic", "token", or "condition" separately.